# Making animations and moving JFrames

Tags: java

1) How can I make an animation on a JFrame which, say, only plays when a certain button is pressed?

2) How can I make a scrolling background, like a map screen?

3) How can I move a JFrame?

4) How can I rotate a JFrame?

Comment: Good question!! What have your tried so far? did you create a jFrame by yourself. Then did you create a button add action listener to it? Break those into smaller portion and try them individually after that if you fail ask question with your failed code.

Comment: Ok, I haven't tried yet, I'll try it now, if it doesn't work I will post my code and the error.

Comment: Also I have no idea how to do number 2, please help me. I have some kind of idea of the others, but absolutely none for number 2.

Comment: you can use jScrollPane for that purpose. https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jscrollpane